# Calling 'RemoveItemFromOrder' of CartModifierFormHandler after already proceeded to checkout by calling 'moveToPurchaseInfo' in ATG

Tags: checkout, atg

**Context:** 
In ATG Commerce - for going into checkout one need to call `moveToPurchaseInfo` method of the `CartModifierFormHandler` which executes the `moveToPurchaseInfo` pipeline chain and check the order/commerce items and validates them. Then, checkout login page will be displayed if the
user has not logged yet. Otherwise user will be directed to the shipping page.

**Requirement:**
Even after going to shipping page user should be able to remove/updateQuantity of items in Cart.

**Question:**
if I want to remove/updateQuanity at this stage, do I just need to call '`RemoveItemFromOrder`' Or if I'll have to call "`moveToPurchaseInfo`" again after any modification in the cart ? Any other alternative to fulfill above requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolving the CartModifierFormhandler you can do something like this

```
String[] skuIds = { "sku10011"};
    CartModifierFormHandler cmfh = (CartModifierFormHandler) ServletUtil            .getCurrentRequest().resolveName("/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CartModifierFormHandler");
    cmfh.setCatalogRefIds(skuIds);
    cmfh.setProductId("prod10010");
    cmfh.setQuantity(12);
    cmfh.handleAddItemToOrder(ServletUtil.getCurrentRequest(),
            ServletUtil.getCurrentResponse());
    order = cmfh.getOrder();
DynamoHttpServletRequest request = ServletUtil.getCurrentRequest();

        request.setParameter("sku2", "13");

        // Set the new quantity for the commerce item being updated.
        cmfh.setCheckForChangedQuantity(true);
        DynamoHttpServletResponse response = request.getResponse();
        cmfh.handleSetOrder(request, response);

        List<CommerceItem> commerceItem = order.getCommerceItems();
        double quantity = commerceItem.get(0).getQuantity();

        assertEquals(13, quantity, 0);
```

@Vihung for making the correction

Answer (score 0):

There is a Update Order Pipeline Chain in ATG Commerce Checkout.
So, whenever there is a change in an Order, during Checkout or before Checkout, the update order chain is always called.

Now if you see your operations:
Update Order / Remove Item from Order - Both are update operations. So everytime you do this kind of update, calling the Update Order Pipeline Chain should suffice. But, make sure that you re-price the order (repriceOrderChain) before calling the Update Order Chain. If you keep digging in the addItemToOrder method, you will know how the call the two pipeline chains to update the order.

Hence, you don't need to use the *moveToPurchaseInfo* because your order was already checked on the Checkout specific parameters when you Moved to Checkout for the first time. And now the only change you are doing is update quantity / remove items.

PS: Do reply if you find anything different.

Regards,
Gaurav E